# Mixing wavelengths to produce light?

Tags: electromagnetism, light, spectrum

It's a mixed part question:

1) Is there any way to add 2 wavelengths outside of the visible spectrum to create a wavelength in the visible spectrum?
2) If this is possible, would those wavelengths be safe?

Comment: @JustJeff, it is not a case of adding two waves in that case. It is saturating a non-linear component. I have built that and it had nothing to do with adding two waves.

Comment: This seems like it could fit on the physics SE.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get frequencies out of a linear system that you didn't put in.  Since passive processes in nature are going to be linear, at least at the individual cycle level, I don't think there is anything that will emit a frequency that is some function of two input frequencies without some sort of active element.  That's not likely possible with today's technology at light frequencies.

Mixers inside radios do make a output frequencies as a function of two input frequencies, but that is at much much lower frequencies.

There are other physical processes that can convert energy from one wavelength to another, but these don't operate over some continuous range as a function of two inputs.  For example, phosphors can essentially convert high frequency light to lower frequency light, but the output frequencies are fixed as a function of electron energy levels in the material.  A incident beam of wide frequency range can heat a object, which then emits black body radiation based on its temperature regardless of the incident frequency.  But these things don't seem to be what you are talking about.

Comment: So basically I can't cross 2 "non-visible" light spectrum waves to produce a visible light spectrum point where they cross?

Comment: @m-y - As Olin said, you can sometimes find materials that will do this for certain specific frequencies, but not for arbitrary frequencies.

Comment: You may be able to pump a material up to a level where it fluoresces using two fequencise but not one. Possibly two transitions with a different pump frequency for each.